# How to reduce a rectangle without problems?

Tags: 2d, android

I'm developing an asteroids' game and I'm needing to reduce the rectangle of the spacecraft because when I use the method intersect() of Rect class to detect a collision with an asteroid they are far.

Here is a part my game:

[image]

As you can see, if the red rectangle of the spacecraft intersects with the red rectangle of the asteroid the game will detect a collision.

My problem it's that there is a big space in the bottom and the top part of the spacecraft which can confuse the player.

To solve it, I'm trying to modify the rect values of top and bottom but when i do this the image dissapear of the canvas.

Comment: Mh why not using circles! Circles are the easiest thing for collision detection. In pure pseudocode: if(radiusObj1 + radiusObj2 > distanceObj1ToObj2) bang();

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several things you could try :

- Subdivide your main ship `bounding box` into smaller bounding boxes .

You can keep the main bounding box as it is now, then if collision is detected, perform additional tests using custom boxes (see picture). You can probably use [Rect](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Rect.html) class and `Intersect()` method to implement this.

While not being perfect it will still be a lot precise that what you have now.

[image] [image]

- use `bounding spheres` for rocks  (see picture)

[image]

Keep main bounding box to check potential collision, and use additional circle collision test for further precision. I dont know if `Android` provide any helpers/classes for this. You can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/401847/circle-rectangle-collision-detection-intersection/402010#402010) for circle to rectangle collision detection examples.

- (Optionally) implement per `pixel collision`. Bounding volumes could still be used but only for preliminary tests. see [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5914911/pixel-perfect-collision-detection-android) for more details

Comment: Do you know how to implement this shapes in Java/Android? I don't find any circle class. Thanks for your answer.

Comment: I have edited answer

Comment: Thanks again. Finally, I think I will use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Path.html and http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Matrix.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem with reducing the rectangle size is that then the ships wing can hit the asteroid and nothing will happen. At that point you're trading accuracy for accuracy, and nobody wins that way.

Alternatively you would want to find a suitable collision or physics (which includes collision) library to handle this part for you. With something like that, you'd be able to define the actual collision shape to better match your objects.

Some notable libraries:

- [Box2d](http://box2d.org/)
- [Chipmunk](http://code.google.com/p/chipmunk-physics/)
- [Bullet (3D physics)](http://bulletphysics.org/)

Otherwise you could use a framework built for Android that takes care of the heavy lifting for you, such as:

- [LibGDX](http://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/)
- [Cocos2d-x](http://www.cocos2d-x.org/)

Comment: "The problem with reducing the rectangle size is that then the ships wing can hit the asteroid and nothing will happen. At that point you're trading accuracy for accuracy, and nobody wins that way." You have reason but I want to reduce the rectangle only in a bit quantity which will balance the wings of the ship with the part that i said.

Comment: using a physics engine doesn't solve the problem of selecting the correct collision shape at all.

Comment: Using a physics engine gives you more objects to choose from. For example, in box2d I could create 3 or 4 shapes to approximately the ship. Using no physics engine or library is going to greatly reduce the possible options.

Answer (score 0):

in my experience in games tells me it is far more acceptable to not have a collision when objects intersect, than the other way round. So i would suggest you to put your collision boxes inside of your objects. Then you can also compose your collision of the player of several boxes, eg one for the wings and one for the body. Keep in mind it is not a problem at all when they overlap, just make as few as possible. Then there are also more collision shapes available then just boxes. For your asteroids you could use circles, because they match the shape of your asteroids much more than boxes.

Comment: I like your idea of compose the spacecraft with several boxes, I believe I will do it. Do you think adding two more boxes down game performance appreciably? How can I create a circle? I don't find its class.

Comment: I have no idea what framework you are using. I don't even know in what programming language you are programming, I can't help you in finding classes that might be already there.

Comment: I'm not using any framework, I'm developing with Java for Android nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

There is always a trade off on generalisation vs. accuracy. If you are doing basic rectangle intersection, you will never achieve perfect hit detection. You'll simply have to make a decision when it's good enough. However, as you pose this question, it's obvious current implementation is not good enough for you. So you have to decide what is.

Most accurate hit detection will always be pixel by pixel detection. And it's also the computationally most expensive solution. I doubt you need it. But you could benefit from different shapes for your entities. Your ship looks like a triangle, and your asteroids look like circles. It won't be perfect, but it might be good enough. Or, if you for some reason need to use rectangles, break the ship down into several smaller rectangles for hit checking.

You could also use the vectors to "look ahead", and calculate the timestamp for when a collision occurs. Then instead of changing the bounds of an object, you could add timestamp modifiers based on collision angles.

As you see, multiple alternatives ... Pick one that suits your level of need.

Answer (score 0):

Use a rectangle for quick rejection and a convex hull/polygon to approximate the actual intersection. You can use Polygon odd/even intersection test or divide the polygon into smaller triangles and test with them. Regardless you don't necessarily need pixel collision.